# REST API: Send Auth only for the one request

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, authentication, jquery-ajax

I'm working on a little SP On-Premises 2016 project.

I have to make several request to different Site-Collections in the farm. I'm making those requests with an Ajax-Call inside a Script-Editor Webpart.

Some users may not have the rights to access those SiteCollections, yet I don't want the requests to fail. Therefore I'm also sending a Basic-Auth-Header. (cheap but it works.)

The problem: After the successful request, I'm now logged in as the specific user I sent in the header.

How can I send those credentials only once, and prevent being logged in as that user after the request?

Comment: Do you have access to sharepoint server(backend)? If you have an access to deploy your own wsp you can simply build custom web service and apply impersonalization. I can help you if you can deploy wsp to the farm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a middle-tier or farm solution (WSP) to do this properly. You don't want to embed credentials into the script editor webpart, of course. What you can do is call an endpoint (middle tier) which possess the necessary rights.

You will want to look into creating a SharePoint Addin (i.e. CSOM solution) to prevent the middle-tier from being called by an anonymous request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sure this solution would have worked, but I didn't have the time for that. I've solved it by just making the content I was trying to fetch static :)

Nevertheless I'm going to accept this answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When making request to different Site-Collections using api, we need to get other site FormDigestValue then add to request header.

[image]

You could refer to this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/f52d252e-538a-4d56-ad89-2a23c57abf34/update-list-in-different-site-collection-using-the-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment